# Find the range of function $f(x)=(a+\sin x )(a+\cos x) \ \ : a > 0$ without use derivative

Tags: calculus

Find the range of function $f(x)=(a+\sin x )(a+\cos x) \ \ : a > 0$ 
without use derivative .

My Try :

$$f(x)=(a+\sin x )(a+\cos x) \ \ : a > 0 $$

$$f(x)=a^2+a\cos x +a\sin x+\sin x\cos x $$

$$f(x)=a^2+a(\sin x+\cos x)+ \dfrac{1}{2}(\sin 2 x)$$

Now what ?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) \leq a^{2}+a\sqrt {1+2\sin\, x\cos \, x}+
 \frac 1 2 \sin(2x)=a^{2}+a\sqrt {1+\sin (2x)} +\frac 1 2 \sin(2x)$. So $f(x) \leq a^{2}+\sqrt 2 a+\frac 1 2$ and this value is attained when $x =\pi /4$. I will leave the minimum to you.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Maximum:
$\sin x+\cos x$ is at its greatest when $\sin x=\cos x\to x=\frac\pi4$

Minimum: $\sin (n\pi)=0$, what is $\cos(n\pi)$?. Notice that this function is more affected by $\sin x$ than $\cos x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sin x+\cos x=u\implies-\sqrt2\le u\sqrt2$

$$f(u)=a^2+au+\dfrac{u^2-1}2=a^2-\dfrac12+\dfrac{(u+a)^2}2-\dfrac{a^2}2$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum:

$\sin x +\cos x=$

$√2\sin (π/4+x).$

$f(x)= a^2+a√2\sin(π/4+x)+$

$(1/2)\sin (2x).$

For $x=π/4$:

$\sin(π/4+x)=1$, $\sin 2x=1$.

Hence $f_{max} =a^2+√2a+1/2$;